# Little o notation - equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I need to help with mathematical problem. Let's have function $g(n) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ and $2$ sets defined:
$$o(g(n)) = \{f(n) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+\;|\; \forall c \in \mathbb{R}^
+\; \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\; ∀n \geq n_0 : f(n) < c · g(n)\}
\\ and \\
\bar{o}(g(n)) = \{f(n) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^
+\;|\;\forall c \in \mathbb{R}^
+\; \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\; \forall n \geq n_0 : f(n) \leq c · g(n)\}$$
How can I prove that $o(g(n))$ is equal to $\bar{o}(g(n))$? Which consequence does it have to definition of little o ($o$)?

I know that $o(g(n)) \implies \bar{o}(g(n))$ side of equivalence should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f\in\bar o(g)$. To prove $f\in o(g)$, let $c$ be any positive number. Since $f\in \bar o(g)$, there exists a natural number $n_0$ such that, for all $n\ge n_0$,  we have
$$f(n)\le \frac c2g(n)<cg(n).$$