# Prove statement is equivalent to little-o notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

This question has already been asked here: [Little o notation - equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533365/little-o-notation-equivalence), however, non of the answers I found were correct/thorough enough.

**The question is:**

I need to help with mathematical problem. Let's have function $g(n) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ and $2$ sets defined:
$$o(g(n)) = \{f(n) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+\;|\; \forall c \in \mathbb{R}^
+\; \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\; ∀n \geq n_0 : f(n) < c · g(n)\}
\\ and \\
\bar{o}(g(n)) = \{f(n) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^
+\;|\;\forall c \in \mathbb{R}^
+\; \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\; \forall n \geq n_0 : f(n) \leq c · g(n)\}$$
How can I prove that $o(g(n))$ is equal to $\bar{o}(g(n))$? Which consequence does it have to definition of little o ($o$)?

I know that $o(g(n)) \implies \bar{o}(g(n))$ side of equivalence should be trivial.

**The only answer is this:**
Let $f\in\bar o(g)$. To prove $f\in o(g)$, let $c$ be any positive number. Since $f\in \bar o(g)$, there exists a natural number $n_0$ such that, for all $n\ge n_0$,  we have
$$f(n)\le \frac c2g(n)<cg(n).$$

**My question** is, is the answer correct? And if it is, why can you divide one $c$ by 2? If it is not, what is the correct answer?

Comment: Since the statement $f(n)\le c\cdot g(n)$ should be true for any $c\in \mathbb R^+$, it is also true for $\dfrac{c}{2}$.

Comment: but can you change one c and not the other?

Comment: Yes. We can choose them independently. See my answer below for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove $f\in o(g)$, all we need to show is that for any positive number $\color{blue}c$, $\exists \color{blue}{n_0}$ such that $\forall n\ge \color{blue}{n_0}$, we have $f(n) \color{red} < \color{blue}c · g(n)$. For this, we first choose a positive number $\color{blue}c$.

Now if $f\in \bar o(g)$, then for any positive number $\color{green}{c'}$, $\exists \color{green}{n_0'}$ such that $\forall n\ge \color{green}{n_0'}$, we have $f(n) \color{red}\le \color{green}{c'} · g(n)$. Since the statement says we can pick any positive number, we cleverly choose $c'=\dfrac{c}{2}$. With this we have,
$$
f(n) \le \frac{c}{2} · g(n)\quad\forall n\ge n_0'
$$
Now, we know that $\dfrac{c}{2}<c$ which means $\dfrac{c}{2}\cdot g(n)<c\cdot g(n)$ so we write the above expression as
$$
f(n) \le \frac{c}{2} · g(n)<c\cdot g(n)
$$
which implies,
$$
f(n)<c\cdot g(n)\quad \forall n\ge n_0'
$$
We started with any $\color{blue}{c}$ and found a corresponding $\color{blue}{n_0}(=\color{green}{n_0'})$ such that $f(n) \color{red} < \color{blue}c · g(n),\forall n\ge \color{blue}{n_0}$. Hence $f\in o(g)$.

So it doesn't matter that we have used $\dfrac{c}{2}$ in the condition of $f\in \bar o(g)$ (we could have chosen $\dfrac{c}{3},\dfrac{c}{4},\dfrac{c}{5}$ etc.). We just wanted to arrive at a strict inequality $<$ from $\le$.